# MySQL 5.0 Show create trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

The show create trigger statement was introduced only in MySQL 5.1 does anyone know how I could get the original SQL (create) of the trigger in MySQL 5.0

I command show triggers works but it does not contain the create statement.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the information from `Information_schema`.`triggers` table: trigger's body and other options; then build CREATE TABLE yourself or write a program that would do it automatically.

Also, you can use object visual editor in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) (free express edition) to view and edit triggers.

Comment: I will have to create the program myself. I was hoping to be able to just use an already created version of it.

Answer (score 1):

mysqldump will output the triggers in the correct format.